# What does #Task<T> indicate in an F# function signature?

Tags: f#

In the following sample code:

```ml
namespace MyNamespace

open System.Threading.Tasks

module MyModule =

    let handler fn = task { return! fn () }
```

If I hover the handler function the signature is:
`val handler: fn: (unit -> #Task<'b>) -> Task<'b>`

I haven't see the #Task before. What is the meaning of the # sign in this case?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/flexible-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#Task<'t>` is short for `'a when 'a :> Task<'t>` - that is, any subtype of `Task<'t>`